# Adjunction formula in Griffiths Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

In the book Griffiths and Harris, they states that: $N^*_V=[-V]|_V$, here $V$ a smooth hypersurface, $N^*_V$ means the conormal bundle w.r.t. $V$.

They define the transition function of $V$ as $g_{\alpha\beta}=f_{\alpha}/f_{\beta}$. The local section of $N^*_V$ on $U_{\alpha}$given by $df_{\alpha}$.And they calculate that:

$df_{\alpha}=g_{\alpha\beta}df_{\beta}$.

Doesn't this formula means that the transition function of $N^*_V$ is $g_{\alpha\beta}$, hence it's isomorphic to $[V]$? I'm quite confused about this part, I would be appreciated if any one can help me.

Comment: No: this means that the $ df_{\alpha} $ glue together to give a global section of $ N_V^* \otimes [V]|_V $. This section is nonvanishing therefore the above mentioned bundle is trivial, hence..

Comment: @CraniumClamp But they say the transition function of $V$ is $g_{\alpha\beta}$, more explicitly, $f_{\alpha}=g_{\alpha\beta}f_{\beta}$, doesn't it means that the transition  coincides with the transition of $N^*_V$?

Comment: The confusion here arises, as it often does, because $f_\alpha$, $f_\beta$ are actual functions. However, $df_\alpha$ and $df_\beta$ are sections of $N^*_V$, not functions. Think of this like in linear algebra: The way coordinates transform is the opposite of the way basis vectors transform. What Cranium said is an easy way to put this all together simply.

Comment: @TedShifrin Got it! Thanks you professor!